# SQALE Plugin for Sonarqube 5.6.6 LTS

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.6, technical-debt

We are trying to upgrade from 4.5.6 to 5.6.6 LTS. Already have a commercial license for SQALE. The latest version of Sqale plugin 2.7 ( http://www.sonarplugins.com/sqale) is not working on 5.6.6. Is there a version available for 5.6.6?

Comment: You should contact Support for commercial products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page you have looked you can read it is compatable until version 5.4. The plugin will not be updated anymore: it is replaced by the SonarQube Quality Model. You can find more details [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-184).